# How can I inject an InstancePerLifetimeScope object into a SingleInstance object outside of ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a console application using Autofac. This application accepts messages from an AMQP queue and does stuff with them. Each time a message is received, the application creates a new Autofac lifetime scope and registers a few things in it; notably, a class (let's call it `Context`) containing information about the message and the user who triggered it. Most of the actual functionality (a set of service classes with an obnoxiously large dependency tree) is registered in the root Autofac scope as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. This causes a lot of memory allocation and a bit of delay as all these classes are re-instantiated every time a message is received.

I would like to turn most of those service classes into `SingleInstance` dependencies, since they are conceptually just containers for functions, and have no state beyond the dependencies injected into them. Autofac won't let me do this because the `Context` objects I'm injecting are `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. That's fine, that shouldn't work for obvious reasons (the context would become outdated after one message and Autofac has no way to re-inject it without reinstantiating the whole object).

However, this is the case even if I inject a `Func<Context>` or a `ContextProvider` object. I understand that this is because Autofac still looks for the `Context` that these should return in the root scope where I registered the `SingleInstance` classes, and not within the current lifetime scope.

So, **is there a way to have Autofac inject a function that does something like `() => GetCurrentInnermostLifetimeScope().Resolve<Context>()`?**

I've seen a few other SO questions about this, but they all fall into two categories: either "register everything as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`" (which I'm trying to avoid), or "use ASP.NET's `DependencyResolver.Current`" (which isn't a thing in console applications).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this, but they will probably incur as much cost if not more than how you are currently doing it. Before trying to make *everything* a singleton, I'd suggest profiling and finding the ones that are actually impacting performance. This kind of request sounds like premature optimization, and also breaks out of some well-defined patterns.

> I would like to turn most of those service classes into SingleInstance dependencies, since they are conceptually just containers for functions, and have no state beyond the dependencies injected into them.

That means the *do* have state. Why does it matter that they don't have any other state in them? For example, one of their dependencies may have state that would therefore necessitate keeping the parent scoped as a per-request as well. The lifetime scopes help you identify the layer at which you can have a singleton and it appears that yours does not.

That being said, there are ways around this. I'll give an example that is similar to the way that ASP.NET Core provides access to `HttpContext` via a singleton. This assumes you are using `Task` based processing; if not, then this won't help but may be adapted. Something has to provide context, and I'll use `AsyncLocal<T>`; if each request gets its own thread, you could try `[ThreadStatic]`.

```cs
using Autofac;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InstanceRequest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<ScopeAccessor>()
                .AsSelf()
                .As<IResolver>()
                .SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<SingleInstance>()
                .SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<IdAccessor>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<Request>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            using (var container = builder.Build())
            {
                await RunAsync(container);
            }
        }

        private static async Task RunAsync(IContainer container)
        {
            var accessor = container.Resolve<ScopeAccessor>();

            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(async id =>
            {
                using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
                {
                    accessor.CurrentScope = scope;

                    await scope.Resolve<Request>().RunAsync();
                }
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }

    class Request
    {
        private readonly IdAccessor _id;
        private readonly SingleInstance _s;

        public Request(IdAccessor id, SingleInstance s)
        {
            _id = id;
            _s = s;
        }

        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var fromScoped = _id.Id;
                var fromSingleton = _s.Id;

                if (fromScoped != fromSingleton)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"{fromScoped} == {fromSingleton}");

                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
        }
    }

    class SingleInstance
    {
        private readonly IResolver _resolver;

        public SingleInstance(IResolver resolver)
        {
            _resolver = resolver;
        }

        public int Id => _resolver.Resolve<IdAccessor>().Id;
    }

    interface IResolver
    {
        T Resolve<T>();
    }

    class ScopeAccessor : IResolver
    {
        private readonly AsyncLocal<ILifetimeScope> _scope = new AsyncLocal<ILifetimeScope>();

        public ILifetimeScope CurrentScope
        {
            get => _scope.Value;
            set => _scope.Value = value;
        }

        public T Resolve<T>() => CurrentScope.Resolve<T>();
    }

    class IdAccessor
    {
        private static int _id = 0;

        public IdAccessor()
        {
            Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref _id);
        }

        public int Id { get; }
    }
}
```

I will note, however, that using something like `AsyncLocal<T>` or `[ThreadStatic]` will incur a non-trivial cost as well and may be more than the GC pressure you think you are experiencing.